# how to create dictionary or json from list of strings in python?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to create dictionary or json from list of strings which is going to be value for dictionary and I have dictionary key that going to be match value. I think it is intuitive for me to get this done, but I have following error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     output[elm].append(k) TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I am curious what cause this problem. can anyone point me out what is wrong with me code?

**my attempt**

here is my code:

**update**

```
lst = {api, 1,0,0}
mystring = lst.split(",")

mystring = ['api', '1', '0', '0']
names = {'name', 'mayor', 'minor', 'patch'}

output =[]
for elm in range(len(names)):
    for k in range(len(mystring)):
        output[elm].append(k)

print(output)
```

how can I fix the error? Is there efficient way to make dictionary or json from list of strings without using nested for loop? any better idea?

**desired output**:

I want to get dictionary or json something like this:

```
{
  "mayor": 1,
  "minor": 0,
  "name": "api",
  "patch": 0
}
```

I am sorry if my coding defect is minor, I couldn't locate source of the problem. thanks

Comment: This is how you create a JSON from a list of strings: `my_json = json.dumps(['abc', 'def', 'ghi'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A neat one-liner:

```
my_string = ['api', '1', '0', '0']
names = ['name', 'mayor', 'minor', 'patch']

output = {names[i]: my_string[i] for i in range(len(my_string))}
print(output)
```

This should give:

```
{'name': 'api', 'mayor': '1', 'minor': '0', 'patch': '0'}
```

Note that your variable `names` is no longer a set; There was no need to have a set. Also, if there was a set, the code wouldn't work because sets are not subscriptable.

There are a lot of errors in your code:
Over here, you are declaring a list, not a dictionary:

```
output =[]
```

Over here you are going over the length of your set and list, you have to go over them:

```
for elm in range(len(names)):
    for k in range(len(mystring)):
```

Comment: @kim -- I don't understand your question. The variable `val` will always be the previous type.

Comment: First of all, that isn't a string, that is a list, and yes-- the type will be preserved.

Comment: I don't seem to get your question; Firstly, `as` is a reserved keyword, and you can't convert a list to an int.

Comment: `api,1,0,0` is not a string, its a list.

Comment: right, my mistake. if it is list, how do we create dictionary? could you update your answer? I am going to accept your answer.

Comment: @kim -- Seems like it's not coming to you; Here is the link I gave on dict comprehension: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension

Comment: In fact you don't need dict comprehension here, using `dict()` constructor is fine, see the other anwser.

Comment: @Xilpex why output is not as same as desired output? it should be {'patch': 'api', 'mayor': 1, 'minor': 0, 'name': 0}. seems order is not strictly preserved. how to fix this?

Comment: @kim -- Dictionary are *not ordered*. They are hash maps, and they have *no* order. If you want an ordered one, use `OrderedDict`.

Comment: @kim -- I've fixed it; Seems like there was a glitch in py code.

Comment: @kim -- The variable `names` is no longer a set. I had changed it to list. Sets wouldn't work in your case.

Comment: @kim -- The solution is very efficient; There is no need to use `OrderedDict` unless you want the key-value pairs to be in the same order, which for most cases is not needed. Also, `OrderedDict` will no longer have an `O(n)` look-up time.

Answer (score 1):

Use builtin [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function. Zip works on lists, so you need to convert your set to list first. Of cause it's not a good idea to rely on the order in the set, so it's better to create both lists as list

```
mystring = ['api', '1', '0', '0']
names = {'name', 'mayor', 'minor', 'patch'}
output = zip(list(names),mystring)
print(dict(output))
```

or using two lists as an input

```
mystring = ['api', '1', '0', '0']
names = ['name', 'mayor', 'minor', 'patch']
output = zip(names, mystring)
print(dict(output))
```

Both prints

```
{'name': 'api', 'patch': '1', 'mayor': '0', 'minor': '0'}
```

Of cause if you want numbers to be a number and not string, make sure their types are correct in the list that you pass to `zip`:

```
mystring = ['api', 1, 0, 0]
names = {'name', 'mayor', 'minor', 'patch'}
output = zip(list(names),mystring)
print(dict(output))
```

prints

```
{'patch': 'api', 'minor': 1, 'mayor': 0, 'name': 0}
```

Comment: This looks like a copy of my answer.

Comment: They not. Async events may look like causual, but they're not

Comment: @Robert Navado why output is not as same as desired output.it should be {'patch': 'api', 'mayor': 1, 'minor': 0, 'name': 0}. seems order is not strictly preserved. how to fix this?

Comment: @kim In order to keep the order, `names` needs to be a list and not a set as in your example. Indeed, a set is *not* ordered.

Comment: When you're using set the order is not guaranteed. You should be using lists all the way to preserve order.